# How to find views per day with Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api

I'm able to get view count with Youtube API v3, but does anyone know how get the number of views per day?  Any suggestions on how to scrape this data would be great.

Apparently it's possible:
[How does one pull statistics (either daily or over time) from the YouTube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650767/how-does-one-pull-statistics-either-daily-or-over-time-from-the-youtube-api)
but the person who commented how to do it now has a broken link.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to pull in the total views every day and calculate the difference yourself.